# php: array item set to another array item (sibling)

Tags: php, arrays, key

The item **'reference'** in the array is set to `$array['fruit']`. But no is value returned

```
$array = array(
          'fruit'=>'apple',
          'reference'=>$array['fruit']
         );
```

example: `echo $array['reference']; //the word apple should be displayed`

How is this result achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are actually referencing the $array variable while creating it so it's normal it'll contain nothing.

This'll work but to be honest, it's kinda sketchy what you are doing.

```
$array = array('fruit' => 'apple');
$array['reference'] = $array['fruit'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set it later, because `$array` isn't initialized yet while you're already assigning.

```
$array = array(
    'fruit' => 'apple'
);

$array['reference'] = &$array['fruit'];
```

The ampersand will create a reference to the index `fruit`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$array = array();
$array['fruit'] = "apple";
$array['reference'] = $array['fruit'];
```